# Hide output from subprocess.check_call. Not working with stderr and stdout

Tags: python, subprocess

I call another script with subprocess.check_call and I do not want to see on my console prints from the other script.
I tried: stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL and stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL, but I still see some output printed.

With one of my script worked with stderr and with one with stdout.
Why is not working?

```
subprocess.check_call(cmd, timeout=timeout_sec, shell=True,  stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

What can I found If I need stdout or stderr?

Comment: Is the subprocess maybe opening `/dev/tty` and printing to that? This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50072485/530160) suggests using `setsid()` to block this, which you can do using subprocess by passing `start_new_session=True` to `check_call()`.

Comment: Not working, I tried start_new_session=True

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `check_call`, I use `run`, which offers more options.

```py
import subprocess


def main():
    cmd = ["./doit.sh"]  # Can be anything
    timeout_sec = 10

    completed_process = subprocess.run(
        cmd,
        timeout=timeout_sec,
        shell=True,
        check=True,  # Behave like check_call
        text=True,  # Capture stdout, stderr as text, not bytes
        capture_output=True,  # Capture to internal .stdout, .stderr
    )

    # Do something with stdout and stderr
    print("STDOUT:")
    print(completed_process.stdout)
    print("STDERR:")
    print(completed_process.stderr)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

## Notes

- The `run` function returns a [CompletedProcess](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CompletedProcess) object, which includes stdout, stderr among other attributes
- Normally, stdout and stderr are bytes, the `text=True` argument will change that so they are str instead
- The `capture_output=True` argument will suppress printing of stdout and stderr and capture them into attributes of the `CompletedProcess` object.